# Selecting Azure DevOps service connection based on if else logic for tenant selection

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to select a service connection based on if else logic.

I have following two pipelines azure-caller.yml and template.yaml.

**azure-caller.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: directory
    displayName: 'select appropriate environment directory' 
    values:
      - Dev
      - Stage
  

stages:
- template: job-templates/template.yml
  parameters:
    selectdirectory: $(select-directory)
```

**template.yml**

```
parameters:
  selectdirectory: default

stages:
  - stage: A
    variables:
    - name: service-connection
      ${{ if eq(parameters.selectdirectory, 'Dev') }}:
        value: Dev-Service-connection
      ${{ elseif eq(parameters.selectdirectory, 'Stage') }}:
        value: Stage-Service-connection
    jobs:

    - job: Install_terraform
      displayName: Intialize Terraform
      continueOnError: true
      steps:
        - checkout: self
        - task: TerraformInstaller@0
          inputs:
            terraformVersion: '1.0.5'

    - job: Validate_terraform_Plan
      displayName: Validate Terraform
      continueOnError: true
      dependsOn: Install_terraform

      steps:
        - checkout: self

        - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
          inputs:
            provider: 'azurerm'
            command: 'init'
            backendServiceArm: ${{ variables.service-connection }}
            backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'any-rg'
            backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'any-storage'
            backendAzureRmContainerName: 'statefile'
            backendAzureRmKey: abcd.tfstate

        - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
          displayName: 'plan'
          inputs:
            provider: 'azurerm'
            command: 'plan'
            commandOptions: '-out="plan.out"' 
            environmentServiceNameAzureRM: ${{ variables.service-connection }}
```

My tasks are failing because it fetches the value of the service connection at compile time, which is empty.
Azure Caller is a wrapper/main pipeline, and the template is the only one that is allowed to use Dev or Stage service connections for deployment purposes to achieve security. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Your input will be helpful. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported to dynamically specify value of pipeline variable conditionally.

In the YMAL pipeline, you can use the **`if`** conditional to judge using or not using a pipeline variable. You can not use it to judge specifying a value or another one to a pipeline variable.

However, you can dynamically set the input conditionally on a task. See "[**Conditionally set a task input**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-set-a-task-input)".

You also can dynamically specify value of parameter conditionally.

Below is an example to dynamically specify value of parameter conditionally. You can reference it to change your YAML files.

- **template.yml**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: ServiceConnection
  type: string

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    displayName: 'Job A1'
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - task: Bash@3
      displayName: 'Show parameter value'
      inputs:
        targetType: inline
        script: echo "The value of ServiceConnection is ${{ parameters.ServiceConnection }}"
```

- **azure-pipelines.yml**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: directory
  displayName: 'Select appropriate environment directory:'
  type: string
  values:
  - Dev
  - Stage

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    ${{ if eq(parameters.directory, 'Dev') }}:
      ServiceConnection: Dev-Service-connection
    ${{ if eq(parameters.directory, 'Stage') }}:
      ServiceConnection: Stage-Service-connection
```

- **Result**

[image]

[image]

**[UPDATE]**

Dynamically set the input conditionally on the task.

- **template.yml**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: selectdirectory
  type: string

stages:
- stage: A
  displayName: 'Stage A'
  jobs:
  - job: Validate_terraform_Plan
    displayName: 'Validate Terraform'
    . . .
    steps:
    . . .

    - task: TerraformTaskV2@2
      inputs:
        provider: 'azurerm'
        command: 'init'
        ${{ if eq(parameters.selectdirectory, 'Dev') }}:
          backendServiceArm: Dev-Service-connection
        ${{ if eq(parameters.selectdirectory, 'Stage') }}:
          backendServiceArm: Stage-Service-connection
        backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: 'any-rg'
        backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: 'any-storage'
        backendAzureRmContainerName: 'statefile'
        backendAzureRmKey: abcd.tfstate

. . .
```

- **azure-pipelines.yml**

```yaml
parameters:
- name: directory
  displayName: 'Select appropriate environment directory:'
  type: string
  values:
  - Dev
  - Stage

stages:
- template: template.yml
  parameters:
    selectdirectory: ${{ parameters.directory }}
```

Comment: Thx for your response, i know what you have posted works, i had it done in similar way, however I had this before myself, how do you cater security aspect, i.e. azure-pipelines.yml is sort of a wrapper pipeline for the template, all the developers will have access to the wrapper pipeline and to change the logic, whereas they dont have the access to template.yml hence the logic of service connection is hidden in the template.yml, how do you cater the security concern?

Comment: hi @lavoizer, if you want to make the logic of service connection be security. As I also have mentioned, you can dynamically set the input conditionally on the task. I have updated my above answer with more details. Please check it.

Comment: This is neat! I already had a solution sort of a workaround, however this one looks cool to me, I will try it sometimes within this week and will keep you posted. Once again thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this answer out: [AzureDevops: Can we pass dynamic value as service connection in yaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037078/azuredevops-can-we-pass-dynamic-value-as-service-connection-in-yaml/68039755#68039755)

Essentially rather then pass in your service connection name via an if statement have the service connection name stored in a variable.yml file that is determined off your selected directory and will load the appropriate service connection name.

Comment: so couple of considerations I am thinking.

1. Is there a way to limit that variable file to be used by only a specific pipeline?
2. How can I use variable template file within a template?, maybe use it within a stage of the template?

Comment: I'm not sure on limiting the yaml file. This could be possible as it would be treated like any other git file in a separate repo. As for the template with a variable. Variables can be scoped at the pipeline, stage, or job. A job template can call a variable template same with a stage. If it helps can always download the expanded yaml and see how it works or write the variables in use as output of a powershell script in the job.