# Azure Pass variable group to Service connection

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want to pass/access variable groups linked to my pipeline in my service connection. I cant find any articles or doc showing how to do so.

Is there a different way to dynamically create service connections using variable groups ?

**Where I need the variables**

[image]

**where variables are located**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** Since this is classic release the service connection must be known before hand. In YAML this can be loaded at compilation time. The only way I am aware of doing this is via an ADO Variable template file in YAML Pipelines. [Here is a link to how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037078/azuredevops-can-we-pass-dynamic-value-as-service-connection-in-yaml/68039755#68039755)

Here is the MS documentation on [using custom variables in Classic Releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321#use-custom-variables)

Answer (score 0):

No. Service connections cannot be dynamically generated. The service connection reference has to be resolved and validated before the pipeline can even start running.

Comment: This is not 100% accurate. If using YAML Pipelines this can be passed in via a YAML template file at compilation.

Comment: @DreadedFrost It's accurate. If the service connection doesn't exist yet, the template compilation will fail.