# passing variables to template - Azure Devops yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am trying to pass variables to a template file in Azure Devops (yaml).

I have a task (all within the same stage) that sets this variable

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=EnvComponetIDDDCL]$envrionment_Component_ID"
```

I can do a

```
Write-Host $(EnvComponetIDDDCL)
```

In a later task (within the same stage and it works fine)

I need to now pass this variable into a template like this :

```
> - template: ../steps/PatchSuccessToDb.yml   parameters:
>     environment: ${{ parameters.environment}}
>     environmentDisplayName: ${{ parameters.environmentServiceConnection }}
>     id: $(EnvComponetIDDDCL)
```

So I have set a parameter as id and set it as the variable.

And then in the template, I have done this :

```
- powershell: |
   
   Write-Host $(SqlServerName)
   Write-Host $(ResourceGroup)
   Write-Host ${{ parameters.id }}
```

The other two come in find but the parameters.id brings an error :

> - Write-Host $(EnvComponetIDDDCL)
> - ```
>            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (EnvComponetIDDDCL:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

So it us literally using the id: $(EnvComponetIDDDCL) and not getting the value within the variable - although I am in the same stage and I could get the value of that variable if it wasn't within a template.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass dynamic variables as parameters to templates.
This is because the template and its parameters are evaluated at [compile time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#process-the-pipeline), long before your pipeline variable has come into existence.

I suggest removing the parameter, and change the template to simply refer to the variable directly. That will get evaluated at [run-time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops#run-each-step), so it will be aware of the variable created by the previous task:

```
- powershell: |
   
   Write-Host $(SqlServerName)
   Write-Host $(ResourceGroup)
   Write-Host $(EnvComponetIDDDCL)
```

Comment: The only thing with this approach it will limit scalability of the template. This will only work since the template will expand into the stage and be reference via inheritance of scope.  This means the task template cannot be reused outside the scope of the given variable assignment.

Comment: I know; I would *like* to be able to use runtime variables as parameters, but it isn't supported so I can't.

Comment: If they are known can store them in a variable file which can be dynamically loaded based on the condition as an alternative....Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68037078/azuredevops-can-we-pass-dynamic-value-as-service-connection-in-yaml/68039755#68039755 and after posting this recognize your runtime comment.....

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the following:

```
  - template: templates/steps/setproxy.yml
    parameters:
      pool_name: ${{ parameters.pool_name }}
```

And in the template:

```
parameters:
  - name: pool_name
```

Inside the template the parameter is used as usual as `${{ parameters.pool_name }}`.

And my parameters is passed and used correctly. It should work also in your case.